# Node.JS + SQL Server + MongoDB + Redis on cloud

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, heroku, redis

My typical requirement is I want NodeJS application which interacts with SQL Server, MongoDb and redis on cloud.

Since this application will be using legacy database I cannot replace SQL Server.

NodeJS + MongoDB + Redis supported very well on Heroku.

NodeJS + MongoDB + SQL Server supported very well on Azure. (Redis support is there but via   vm)

What are the recommendations for using all the components together?

Comment: What do you mean, "recommendations"?

Comment: I mean any other cloud solution other than Azure or heroku. Or better way out in Azure or heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it basically comes down to the decision, if you need Redis or not. While it's possible to get Redis running on Windows, or - as you mentioned - via a VM (potentially running on the same system, I assume?). Running it natively on Windows is not supported, and judging by a few experiments, I wouldn't recommend it for production-use either.

If you simply use Redis as a session-storage, you might as well put that part on MongoDB, and thus use the Azure-Solution. If you need Redis for anything else, you might end up with a scenario like me:

We're running Node.JS+REDIS+MongoDB on Linux, and MSSQL runs on a separate Windows-Machine. The connection from Node.JS to MSSQL is done via ODBC/FreeTDS, which performs well for the requirements I have (all other solutions in fact didn't work very well).

Reason we went for that was simply, that we at one point will remove the SQL-Server from the setup, once the transition is fully done.

Comment: Just found amazon ec2 supports sql server out of the box. How good is this solution?

Comment: I don't see any reason, why the stack Node.JS+MongoDB+SQLServer wouldn't work - and if Redis wasn't a requirement, you can go for any "windows in a cloud"-solution

Comment: I shall go with your solution Node.JS + Redis + MongoDB on Linux Amazon ec2 and MSSQL also on amazon EC2. Amazon EC2 provides SQL Server service. Thanks.